# Why am I getting Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN" when setting up a 3LO authentication with nodemailer and googleapis?

Tags: next.js, google-api, smtp, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer and googleapis to send emails from my Next.js API route but I am getting the following error: Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"

I followed this tutorial to set it up: https://blog.devgenius.io/correct-way-in-setting-up-nodemailer-for-email-service-946f6bfd73e8

I additionally looked at the nodemailer documentation to get sure that everything is up to date.
Nodemailer documentation example for a 3LO authentication setup: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#example-3

Here is my code:

```
const handleSendVerificationEmail = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const { body } = req
    const { email }: { email: string } = body

    const user = process.env.GOOGLE_EMAIL_ADDRESS
    const clientId = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_MAIL
    const clientSecret = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET_MAIL
    const refreshToken = process.env.GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN
    const redirectURI = process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI

    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectURI)
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: refreshToken })

    try {
        const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken()

        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: true,
            auth: {
                type: '0Auth2',
                user,
                clientId,
                clientSecret,
                refreshToken,
                accessToken
            },
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        })

        const mailOptions = {
            from: `YourTable <${user}>`,
            to: email,
            subject: 'Hello from gmail using API',
            text: 'Hello from gmail email using API',
            html: '<h1>Hello from gmail email using API</h1>'
        }

        const result = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
        res.status(200).json({ email })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Unable to send verification email' })
    }
}

export default handleSendVerificationEmail
```

I also added the tls property to the transporter as suggested in some of the tutorials I found even though it did not fix the problem.

I also tried to skip the properties host, port and secure and replaced them with service. Again, that did not make a difference.

As suggested in the comments I followed the instructions and I changed my code accordingly to this:

```
 const user = process.env.GOOGLE_EMAIL
        const pass = process.env.GOOGLE_APP_PASSWORD

        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            port: 465,
            host: "smtp.gmail.com",
            auth: {
              user: user,
              pass: pass
            },
            secure: true
          })

        const mailOptions = {
            from: `YourTable <${user}>`,
            to: email,
            subject: 'Hello from gmail using API',
            text: 'Hello from gmail email using API',
            html: '<h1>Hello from gmail email using API</h1>'
        }

        const result = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
```

But again the same error appeared:

```
Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (H:\Dokumente\Programming_Projects\yourtable\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:790:19)
    at SMTPConnection.login (H:\Dokumente\Programming_Projects\yourtable\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:444:38)
    at H:\Dokumente\Programming_Projects\yourtable\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-transport\index.js:272:32
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (H:\Dokumente\Programming_Projects\yourtable\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:213:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:641:28)
    at SMTPConnection.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at SMTPConnection.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (H:\Dokumente\Programming_Projects\yourtable\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1325:14)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (H:\Dokumente\Programming_Projects\yourtable\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:953:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (H:\Dokumente\Programming_Projects\yourtable\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:755:14) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  command: 'API'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the tranporter to this and it finally worked:

```
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            Service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
                user: user,
                pass: pass
            },
            port: 465,
            host: "smtp.gmail.com"
        })
```

However, I still did not find a solution to make it work with 0Auth 2.0 via Google APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, Here is how I fixed it. Because I used Gmail I had to enable 2-factor authentication and then add Nodemailer
to **App Passwords** [App Password Settings](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords) then use the generated password as the password for authentication

```js
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        port: 465,
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        auth: {
          user: GMAIL_FROM,
          pass: PASSWORD, // generated from the App Passwords
        },
        secure: true,
      })
```